# Oracle -- Update the exact column referenced in the ON clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I think this requirement is rarely encountered so I couldn't search for similar questions.

I have a table that needs to update the ID. For example ID 123 in table1 is actually supposed to be 456. I have a separate reference table built that stores the mapping (e.g. old 123 maps to new id 456).

I used the below query but apparently it returned error 38104, columns referenced in the ON clause cannot be updated.

```
MERGE INTO table1 
USING ref_table ON (table1.ID = ref_table.ID_Old)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET table.ID = ref_table.ID_New;
```

Is there other way to achieve my purpose?

Thanks and much appreciated for your answer!

Comment: try to use rowid for ON clause

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan they're two different tables, rowid won't match

Comment: @DaveCosta ok, you're right, i shouldn't give a short answer. Refer to MT0's answer below for detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update a column used in the `ON` clause in a `MERGE`.  But if you don't need to make other changes that `MERGE` allows like `WHEN NOT MATCHED` or deleting, etc. you can just use a `UPDATE` to achieve this.

You mentioned this is an `ID` that needs an update.  Here's an example using a scalar subquery.  As it is an `ID`, this presumes `UNIQUE` `ID_OLD` values in `REF_TABLE`. I wasn't sure if *Every* row needs an update or only a sub-set, so set the update here to only update rows that have a value in `REF_TABLE`.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
  ID NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE REF_TABLE(
  ID_OLD NUMBER,
  ID_NEW NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (100);

INSERT INTO REF_TABLE VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO REF_TABLE VALUES (2,20);
```

Initial State:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

ID   
1    
2    
100
```

Then make the `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET TABLE1.ID = (SELECT REF_TABLE.ID_NEW
                 FROM REF_TABLE
                 WHERE REF_TABLE.ID_OLD = ID)
WHERE TABLE1.ID IN (SELECT REF_TABLE.ID_OLD
                    FROM REF_TABLE);

2 rows updated.
```

And check the change:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

ID   
10   
20   
100
```

Comment: Add one more condition to WHERE (just in case the REF_TABLE allows the new ID to be equal to the old) - `...  where ....  AND id != ref_table.id`. This will avoid updating rows that don't really need updating.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ROWID` pseudocolumn:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6de52/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1( ID ) AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE REF_TABLE( ID_OLD, ID_NEW ) AS
  SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 FROM DUAL;

MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING ( SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
               r.id_new
        FROM   TABLE1 t
               INNER JOIN REF_TABLE r
               ON ( t.id = r.id_old ) ) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET id = src.id_new;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6de52/1/0)**:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  3 |
```

Comment: Just in case the REF_TABLE allows the new id to equal the old, you may want to add at the very end `WHERE id != src.id_new` to avoid updating rows that don't really need it. (This will also avoid attempts to set the id to NULL, if NULL is allowed in the ID_NEW column; such updates to the PK column of the old table would be rejected by the PK constraint anyway.)